# PHP - Calculating time in minutes between dates

Tags: php, date, logic

I'm looking to create a script to count how many hours/mins a contractor has worked within his standby times.

Standby times show a contractors default standby times.

The script needs to count how many minutes the contractor has worked within these hours.  It should also be compatible if the work rolls into a new day (see example below).

**Standby Times**

```
Standby Time From  (Example: 18:00)
Standby Time To    (Example: 06:00)
```

**Travel Start Time**

```
19.30
```

**Site Arrival Time**

```
20.30
```

**Home Time**

```
03:30
```

The above example should return 8 hours 0 mins STANDBY.  I have explained why below.

The contractor travels to work at **19.30**.
The contractor arrives on-site at **20.30**.
The contractor arrives at home at **03:30**.

This means the contractor has spent the hours 19.30 - 03:30 (8hrs) on STANDBY.

Any help appreciated :)

**EDIT**

I originally was using this script, but it doesn't work when the hours worked rolls into two days.

```
// get travel start timestring
$travel_time = 70200; //19:30 in seconds

// get home time in seconds
$home_time = 12600; //03:30 in seconds

// get standby_from and standby_to in seconds
$standby_from = 64800; // 18:00 in seconds
$standby_to = 21600; // 06:00 in seconds

// check how many seconds we worked during standby hours
for($sec_of_day=$travel_time;$sec_of_day<=$home_time;$sec_of_day++)
{
    if($sec_of_day >= $standby_from && $sec_of_day <= $standby_to)
    {
        $seconds_sb++;
    }
}
echo $seconds_sb; // returns how many seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:21:00");
echo round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2). " minute";
```

A simple exemple, you have to convert your date in secondes with strtotime(), and make the difference between the two timestamps.

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question properly.